# A sub-logarithmic complexity in Analysis and N.Th

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, computational-complexity

The question will be about complexity $\ \mathcal C(p)\ $ being positive and the same for all primes $\ p.$

Function $\ \mathcal Q\ $ is defined in the set of finite sequences of positive rational numbers; and
$\ \mathcal C:\mathbb Q_{>0}\to\mathbb R,\ $ where $ \mathbb Q_{>0}\ $
is the set of all positive rational numbers.

Let $\ r=\frac ab\ > 0\ $ be an arbitrary positive rational number where both $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

$$ \mathcal Q(1)\ :=\ \mathcal C(1)\ := 0 $$
and, for $\ r\ne 1,$
$$ \mathcal Q((r))\ :=
    \ \frac 1{\log(a+b)-\log(|a-b|)} $$
(*this doesn't depend on the fractional representation of* $r$) and
$$ \mathcal Q((r_k:\ k=1\ldots n))
    \ =\ \sum_{k=1}^n\,\mathcal Q(r_k) $$
and finally,
$$\ \mathcal C(r)\ :=\ inf \ \sum_{k=1}^n\,\mathcal Q(r_k) $$

where the inf is taken over all expressions:

$$ r\ =\ \prod r_k^{\,t_k} $$

and $\ t_k\ $ are natural numbers (*equivalently*, non-negative integers).

Thus, we have a sublogarithmic inequality:
$$ \mathcal C(r\cdot s)\ \le\ \mathcal C(r) + \mathcal C(s) $$

**Example:** Since $\ 3\ =
     \ \left(\frac98\right)^2\cdot\left(\frac43\right)^3,\ $ we get
$$ \mathcal C(3)\,\ \le\,\ \mathcal Q\left(\frac98\right)
         +\mathcal Q\left(\frac43\right)\,\ \le
    \,\ \frac1{\log(17)}+\frac1{\log(7)} $$

---

---

**Conjecture 1** $\ \mathcal C(r)>0\ $ for every positive rational $r$.

**Conjecture 2** $\ \mathcal C(p)\ =\ \mathcal C(2)\ $ for every prime $\ p.$

---

---

**Remark** *I've formulated the above complexity definition and conjectures in the spring of 1972. The conjectures were somewhat
supported by the identities that I've computed then*:

\begin{array}{lllll}
2\quad = & \left(\frac{126}{125}\right)^{72} & \left(\frac{225}{224}\right)^{27}
                        & \left(\frac{2401}{2400}\right)^{-19} &\left(\frac{4375}{4374}\right)^{31} \\ \\
3\quad = & \left(\frac{126}{125}\right)^{114} & \left(\frac{225}{224}\right)^{43}
                        & \left(\frac{2401}{2400}\right)^{-30} &\left(\frac{4375}{4374}\right)^{49} \\ \\
5\quad = & \left(\frac{126}{125}\right)^{167} & \left(\frac{225}{224}\right)^{63}
                        & \left(\frac{2401}{2400}\right)^{-44} &\left(\frac{4375}{4374}\right)^{72} \\ \\
7\quad = & \left(\frac{126}{125}\right)^{202} & \left(\frac{225}{224}\right)^{76}
                        & \left(\frac{2401}{2400}\right)^{-53} &\left(\frac{4375}{4374}\right)^{87}
\end{array}